# Heroku CSV file upload ephemeral drive

Tags: github, heroku

I've got a Dash app on Heroku that live-updates a CSV file downloaded from Github. Currently, I'm using Requests to download the file and save it as a temp.csv from which I read the data for my various graphs. When a live-update is triggered a new CSV file is pulled from GitHub and the graphs updated. The app works great but after a while heroku fails to read the CSV file, an exception is raised and my app crashes. I know Heroko's storage is Ephemeral and when a dyno restarts then file contents are lost, however my app pulls new CSV files on every live- update so this shouldn't be an issue since I'm don't have a need for permanent storage. The next day, the app is working as normal. My local program doesn't encounter this problem so it must be something with Heroku. Any ideas? I've tried to re-set dynos, refresh the app, but after using the app for 7-8hr in a day this seems to occur.

Comment: I suggest not relying on the ephemeral storage at all. Store your retrieved data in a database instead. Or, if you really must store locally, why not catch the exception and grab the file from GitHub again?

Answer (score 0):

I happen to be naming the files on GitHub by today’s date. I learned that the heroku server as a default uses UTC time zone. I’m on PST, so at around 5pm my time the server was looking for the next days file and my app would crash. (Facepalm)